# Restify getting request.body when content-type is application/octet-stream

Tags: node.js, file-upload, content-type, restify

Does anyone know why setting content-type to application/octet-stream then request body is undefined in restify?

Here is my code

```js
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer({});

server.use(restify.bodyParser({ }));

server.post('/test', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
});

server.listen(8090, function() {});
```

HTTP Request

```
POST /test 
Content-Type: text/plain

hello
```

Console print: hello

```
POST /test 
Content-Type: image/png

hello
```

Console print: <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f>

```
POST /test 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

hello
```

Console print: undefined

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in restify, this is due to the bodyParser only expecting `Content-Type: application/json` extracted from https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/master/lib/plugins/json_body_parser.js#L28

```
if (req.getContentType() !== 'application/json' || !req.body) {
  next();
  return;
}
```

So req.body never gets assigned...